# Print crystal report using dotmatrix printer

Tags: crystal-reports, dot-matrix

I need your help to fix the issue with the page scrolling on the dot matrix printer.
I am using dot-matrix printer to print my bills. Bills are printer perfectly but after the print completes the page rolls extra approx 2"-3".

Can you please help me get rid of this issue.

Comment: bill height vs page height?

Comment: bill height and page height 8"

Comment: many moons since i did this sort of thing, and it wasn't crystal reports. But one problem was windows print server knowing what was 'good' for me and having it's own idea of what the page height was, ended up using the windows raw printer driver. Don't know if it's applicable in your case though.

Answer (score 0):

resolved, its my fault.
I didn't have updated the printer tractor settings to print the bill as per the requirements.